# Removing nodes from queue

Tags: java, queue

I had an exercise to create two methods for simple queue class, first to delete last element and second to delete element at k position. Particularly I'm not asking for better implementation. Is it good enough and elegant ? What I should change ? I'll post only mentioned methods, rest should be simple enough.

```
/**
 * Deletes node at position k.
 */
public void delete(int k) {
    if (k > N || isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot delete element at position: " + k);
    Node previous = first;
    int deleteIndex = 1;

    if(k == deleteIndex){               //special case for first element
        if(first.next == null)
            last = null;
        first = first.next;
        N--;
        return;
    }

    for (Node node = first; node != null; node = node.next, deleteIndex++) {
        if (k == deleteIndex) {
            previous.next = node.next;
            if (previous.next == null) last = previous; //if deleted element was the last one
            N--;
            return;
        }
        previous = node;
    }
}


/**
 * Deletes last node from the queue.
 */
public void removeLastNode() {
    if(isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot delete last element from queue");
    if (N == 1) {           //special case for only one element in queue
        first = null;
        last = null;
        N--;
        return;
    }

    Node previous = null;
    for (Node node = first; node != null; node = node.next) {
        if (node.next == null) {
            previous.next = null;
            last = previous;
            N--;
        }
        previous = node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your code is correct and mostly ok. Except for two things:

- You have 1-based indexing? Follow the *principle of least suprise*, and use zero-based indexing like all other data structures as well.
- Your variable names could be more obvious.

  - `N` seems to be the `length` or `size` of your list – use this longer name instead. Also, the name `N` does not adhere to the best practice that variables and members should start with lowercase characters.
  - `k` is an `index` – the traditional abbreviation for that is `i`.
  - `deleteIndex` is not the index which you want to delete. Rather, it is some iteration variable. I'd call it `position`.

Then there are some minor style issues.

- It is advisable to always use `if` with braces, as it tends to improve readability. If you do not use braces, I would recommend to put the body of the `if` on the same line. You do this with your `isEmpty` guards, but not at `if (first.next == null)`.
- You have very long lines. I recommend using 80–100 characters. Your longest line seems to be 104 characters long with this intendation, which is too long. (Incidentally, your lines get shorter if you use the `if` with curlies…).
- Instead of an `NoSuchElementException` you should consider an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Some parts of your code could be made more obvious, or structured differently:

- In `delete`, you have the test `if (first.next == null)`, where you actually want to test `if (size == 1)`.
- Finding a node at a certain position is so useful that it should have a method of its own. You want a `Node previous = nodeAt(i - 1); ...` instead of the `for` loops.
- If you don't do that, your `for` loops still have the problem that they do three things between iterations: `previous = node; node = node.next; position++`. You have put one of these at the end of the loop body, the rest in the increment statement of the `for` loop. It would have been better to group these together.